# how to add text below image on fancybox plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using the fancybox plugin - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

I can't find where to add the class "data-fancybox-title" that suppose to show the text that is in the title under image when the lightbox open.

I read the documentation but I still didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You HTML would look something like this..

You need to specify the `title` attribute for the `anchor tag`

```
<a rel="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum Title" class="fancybox"   
                  href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
     <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

And to display at the bottom of the image try this

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside',
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not a *class* but an *attribute* and you add it in your `<a>` tag like

```
<a data-fancybox-title="Lorem ipsum" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">Open Image</a>
```

This has the advantage that the browser's tooltip won't show the `title` when you hover the link.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E4qxU/)**

Please notice that `data-*` attributes require a HTML5 `DOCTYPE` to validate properly.

Answer (score 0):

You add it in `title` attribute of the link. Clearly you haven't read the documentation.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5471/9036958611_fa1bb7f827_b.jpg" title="Westfield Waterfalls - Middletown CT Lower (Graham_CS)">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5471/9036958611_fa1bb7f827_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: The OP clearly have read the documentation but he/she was just confused because `data-*` attributes, specially `data-fancybox-*` attributes are still too new for many.